# issue in compiling GWT code with log4j

Tags: gwt, log4j, gwt-log4j

There is a web application of which some functionality is implemented in GWT. An exception coming while compiling gwt code in eclipse via Ant script.

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
FileNotFoundException: \logs\App.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

If I ignore the above exception my application works fine and properly updates the logs in App.log file under the set file path. But due to this exception gwt code id not getting compiled.

In log4j.properties file, below mentioned path is set:

```
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.base}/logs/App.log
```

If I changed this path to absolute(like D:\App.log) than it is running perfectly.
Currently I am running the build on Windows and later the war will be deployed on Linux.

How can I make it compile with relative path? Is there any configuration missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `catalina.base` system property is not defined, then the path becomes the absolute path `/logs/App.log`, which is what's in the error message.

Try to, either:

- remove your `log4j.properties` file from the classpath when compiling your app
- set the `catalina.base` system property to some existing path (a `logs` subfolder might be required) when compiling your app.

Comment: where to set the catalina.base property? I have set the environment variable like CATALINA_HOME but it is still not picking this.I am running it on windows.

Comment: `<sysproperty key="catalina.base" file="foobar" />` in the `<java classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">` that compiles your app. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html